# difference between 'there is not a' and 'there is not any' constructions in the following sentences

Tags: difference, negation

A grammar book I am reading says in some cases 'no' = 'not a' or 'not any', and gives the following two examples:

> (1) We had to walk home because there was no bus. (= there wasn't a bus)

> (2) There were no shops open. (= there weren't any shops open)

Can I say 'We had to walk home because there were not any buses.' without changing the meaning of the first sentence? Similarly, can I say 'There wasn't a shop open.' instead of its plural version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We had to walk home because there were not buses. -*incorrect*

This sentence is almost correct, but you need a determiner when referring to none of something. **no** and **any** are determiners, but **not** is an adverb.

> We had to walk home because there were **not any** buses.
> We had to walk home because there were **no** buses.

> There wasn't a shop open

This sentence is correct, and emphasises that there wasn't even one shop open.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I did omit 'any' before 'buses'. Actually I'd like to ask whether there is difference between 'there were not any buses' and 'there wasn't a bus'. when I would replace 'no' with 'not a' + a singular noun or 'not any' + its plural form in the first sentence.  I'm not sure I've completely understood what you said. So, 'there was no bus', 'there wasn't a bus', and 'there weren't any buses' have the same meaning, and they could only differ in the degree of emphasis, couldn't they?

Comment: You might use the difference to indicate how many buses you were expecting. "There was no bus" -> you weren't expecting one, "There wasn't a bus" -> you were expecting one, but it didn't come. "There weren't any buses" -> you were expecting many buses, but there weren't any.